# Between Node.JS and Express, can someone explain where the Web Server fits in?

Tags: node.js, web-services, express, web

I've recently started server-side development using Node JS and Express but i'm getting confused as to how it all works. From my understanding, The web serve stores the website and returns the pages as they're requested from the browser. Apache is a web server and you would use that for a stack like XAMPP. ASP.NET is a framework that uses IIS Web Server and communicates with that.

But with Node, where's the server? Node is runtime environment and is USED to CREATE a server and Express is a web FRAMEWORK to help with server http requests but what/where is the actual web SERVER? Maybe i'm just not understanding web servers or something? Someone please clarify!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `Node`, we do not need a web server like Apache or a container that sort of, node can listen to a port and act as a server itself,

and `express` is `web application framework for Node` which provides set of features to make life easier.

for a vague comparison, if Node is a telephone then Node + express will be a smartphone. - both can do same stuff but latter have more convenient features.

see below two example of creating a server which  listen to a port 3000,

**In node:**

```
const http = require('http')

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.url)
    response.end('Hello Node.js Server!')
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(3000,() => console.log("app started"));
```

**Node + express**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello express !')
})    

app.listen(3000,() => console.log("app started"));
```

Both does the same thing, but with express things are easier.

Comment: Ahh I see, so node creates a server on the computer you're developing on? So your development PC is also the server?

Comment: While on development we can go with this, and assume you are hosting this some place , say in `heroku` then we should change the line to `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,() => console.log("app started"));` so that it can use the port assigned to it rather than 3000.

Comment: Its creating the server at run time, so it really doesn't have to worry about a server set up, Node will take care of it.